How to preprocess .nifti files such that converting them into .jpg images? Am I doing Correct?
Preprocessing Nifti Files using Python Code
import os
import nibabel as nib
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

def convert_nifti_to_jpeg(nifti_file, output_dir, dpi=300, output_size=(300, 300)):
    # Load NIfTI file
    img = nib.load(nifti_file)
    data = img.get_fdata()

    # Iterate through the slices and save each one as a JPEG image
    for i in range(data.shape[2]):
        # Extract the 2D slice
        slice_data = data[:, :, i]

        # Normalize the pixel values to be between 0 and 255 (for uint8 encoding)
        min_val = np.nanmin(slice_data)
        max_val = np.nanmax(slice_data)

        # Handle division by zero or NaN values
        if min_val == max_val:
            normalized_slice = np.zeros_like(slice_data)
        else:
            normalized_slice = ((slice_data - min_val) / (max_val - min_val) * 255).astype('uint8')

        # Create a PIL Image from the numpy array
        image = Image.fromarray(normalized_slice)

        # Convert the image to mode='L' (grayscale)
        image = image.convert('L')

        # Resize the image to the specified dimensions
        image = image.resize(output_size)

        # Define the output file path
        output_file = os.path.join(output_dir, f'slice_{i}.jpg')

        # Save the image as JPEG with the specified DPI
        image.save(output_file, format='JPEG', dpi=(dpi, dpi))

Converting the .nifti file into .jpg image to train the model.
I have tried to solve the problem but I am confused whether other slices might give something important information? But the other slices do not include the complete brain I confirm this?
For one patient I have four different modelities, all are .nifti files,

Flair
T2
T1
T1ce

I am converting the given .nifti file into 2D slices. It converts the files into 155 slices and the slice 78 is image in which full brain is shown, therefore I am taking the full image of MRI (that is slice 78).
T1ce is enhanced form of T1, therefore, we can ignore T1 (I think so).
Moreover, I am combining the

Flair
T1ce
T2w

into the multi-channel image. Then I am using that multi-channel image for training my model.
This is how they look like at the end.
Result After Combining three modelities:


I recommend you use 3D models, as it is 3D data. Also, all modalities are important! Each one emphasizes different types of tissue. I've trained several models using this data and never converted it to jpg (you will probably run out of memory and lose quality). I just open data as you did and data = np.array(data) at the beginning of the training.

The most common way, from my knowledge, of combining the four modalities is to stack them, so you'll have an array with shape (4, width, height, depth). You may use np.stack((flair_array, t1_array, t1ce_array, t2_array)). As the data is huge, you could consider creating small patches (it's also considered data augmentation).

the first dimension is for batching. the last dimension is for channels. you should stack them like (1, width, height, 4) instead. they're grayscale anyway, so it all works out. np.stack takes parameters saying how to stack the arguments. there is also np.transpose, to reorder dimensions.
